# Is there a different way of splitting numbers into digits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I was looking at a graph visualizing the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) ($\gamma$), like that below, and an interesting question emerged.

**Background:** The Euler-Mascheroni constant, to take the definition directly from the above-linked Wikipedia page, is the [limiting difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) between the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) and the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm). Basically, the "natural log of infinity" (not quite so rigorous), or $\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(x)$, is infinite, and so is the harmonic series, or $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$. But if you subtract this infinite natural log *from* the harmonic series, you get a finite number around $0.57721$, called the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

**Question:** As the harmonic series is a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function), $\gamma$ is the sum of "contributions" from infinitely many sections, shown below as the first purple section covering $x \in [1, 2)$, the second purple section covering $x \in [2, 3)$, the third covering $x \in [3, 4)$, etc.

[image: Euler-Mascheroni constant visualized]

It occurred to me that this is fairly similar to the notion of a number being the sum of its digits, like the number 123 expressed as follows:

[image: 123 Graphed As Digit Step Function]

It could be really useful to be able to express, operate on, and reason about a number with each "digit" representing a different term of a series, beyond the one canonical series in which we currently express all numbers:

$$\textrm{number}=\textrm{digit}_1*\textrm{base}^{n-1}\ +\ \textrm{digit}_2*\textrm{base}^{n-2}\ +\ \textrm{digit}_3*\textrm{base}^{n-3}\ +\ ...\ +\ \textrm{digit}_n*\textrm{base}^0$$

**TL;DR:** Does there exist an area of study within mathematics that generalizes the notion of "digits of a number", allowing for them to be defined by something other than the series directly above, and with its own rules and operations for manipulating such a number? What are its rules and operations?

Comment: Expressions of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b^k$, are plainly polynomials values. The issue now is the unicity of representation...

Comment: In your expansion of $\gamma$, you have a sum of decreasing terms, which might be put in correspondence with the decreasing powers of a base. But where are the digits ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust In my mind, the choice of how to split the terms of $\gamma$ into "base" and "digit" components could ideally vary based on desired application to allow for a more powerful tool. I hoped for an answer specifying some established method of assigning a base to each "place", and some function taking the base and associated "digit" and producing the corresponding term. Given I don't yet have an answer to what this generalization of the notion of "digits of a number" looks like, it's a bit early to say where that split lies as far as $\gamma$ is concerned.

Comment: The fact that such a concept is not in wide use (if in use at all) should hint you that it is of little interest.

Comment: You might be interested in $p$-adic numbers where for example $\ldots 99999 = -1.$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Comment: @md2perpe That should really be an answer, it's a damn good one

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be interested Continued Fractions. Every number has a unique continued fraction representation. Likewise, every continued fraction represents the sequence of best rational approximations to any number. Continued fractions are of finite size if and only if they are rational. Square roots are repeating continued fractions.

Continued fractions can be used to determine "how" rational a given approximation is. For example, in various root finding approximation algrorithms, if you take the numerical decimal and write it as a contninue fraction, you should get a large number (infinty) showing up at one of the digits. This very quickly identifies the numerical solution is converging to a rational.

There are many other examples of their use as well.

Comment: "Every number has a unique continued fraction representation": this is only true for irrational numbers. Rational numbers have [two representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Finite_continued_fractions).

Comment: Apologies, I was ignoring trivialities.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) where for example $\ldots999 = -1$. (Usually $p$ is a prime, though.)